# Expand UiWebView then resize back

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiimageview

I am currently using a UIWebView and UIImageView in one board/activity (iOS Application), now i just managed to animate "Collapse" of UIImageView so it goes away from visible content i done it like this:

```
GCRect newFrame = self.testImageView.frame;
newFrame.origin.x + = 500;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
self.testImageView.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

Now i want that after this happens i expand UIWebView to the top (Not over the status bar) and then i have another method where i animate UIImageView come back and there i would like to again setup the same width as it was before resizing UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method which executes on completion of UIImageView's animation in which you can animate the web view. Set another method on completion of this animation and animate image view to come back there.

Below is some code which will help you:

Add below lines to your animation code.

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished)];
```

Implement this `animationFinished` method and do whatever you want to do on completion of current animation.

You can get more information of this kind of implementation from [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13606-animation-didstop-delegate.html).